# Android Disclosure Indicator Solution

Tags: android, list, disclosure

I developping an Android app based on its iOS twin. In one of our view, we have a list with many information but not necessarily all the information we want. In iOS, they have the right-carret disclosure indicator, but is there an equivalent in Android?

According to this page, http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html, Android app should not have any such thing. But how can I make it clear to the users that there is more info to be shown if they click on the list item?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView and set any icon you want for each item of the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

It's a paradigm of the OS that clicking on list items takes you into a more detailed page. Just simply the fact that it's a list should make it clear to users that there is more information under there as long as the title of the list item is clear. For example the items in the link that you sent make it clear that you can click on them to get more Bluetooth or WiFi settings.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but my rows are jam-packed with information and since our target audience is older, we want to have an icon. I'll just make one and add one but I was wondering if there was just an option to add one without coding it myself.

Comment: There is not an option without making one yourself. It's easy enough since you're already using custom layouts for your rows.

Comment: Yeah, it's no problem, but it's a nice thing in iOS that you don't have to worry ;)